# Angularitics with HBS files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, event-handling, handlebars.js

I've attached Angular to my .hbs project so I could access the ease of use of using the angularitics attributes to attach to my links. However, the only links that appear to track something other than "pageview" (like my category and labels) are ones directing to a new tab with target="_blank"

In short, my angularitics (google analytics) events are firing, but they only pass an EVENT when I have target="_blank"

Is this something in handlebars? Or could some javascript somewhere else be catching the event before it fires off properly?

Again to be clear, angularitics is firing pageviews instead of events (and pageviews if it's an internal link).

Answer (score 0):

It ends up the events were being passed through, but since the page was reloading, "preserve log" needed to be enabled so that I could actually see the events before new files and network calls refreshed.

So the answer is, preserve the network log to watch event traffic when changing pages.